# Sum individual columns while looping over SQLServer result set

Tags: php, sql-server, loops, sum

I have a SQLServer query result and I need to get the sum of values from multiple columns. How can I get the grand total of each column?

```
while (odbc_fetch_array($connection, $sqlcommand)) 
{         
    $var1 = odbc_result($conn, 1);
    $var2 = odbc_result($conn, 2);
    $var3 = odbc_result($conn, 3);
};
```

Then I get data like so

```
 1  | 250 | 300
 50 |  22 | 123
 22 |  71 | 225
```

**How do I get sum of the columns?** I tried `sum(odbc_result($cur, 1))` but it does not work. For example first column would be `73`.

Comment: Why don't you use `SUM()` in the SQL?

Comment: Use [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php). As far as I know, PHP does not have a `sum` function. Also, if I'm reading the manual right, `odbc_result` returns a string. But if you want to sum things, you need numbers (or at least something summable). If you're getting the strings with `|` and all from MySQL, PHP can't sum those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accumulate the sums in variables:

```
$sum1 = 0;
$sum2 = 0;
$sum3 = 0;
while (odbc_fetch_array($conn, $sqlcommand)) 
{         
    $sum1 += odbc_result($conn, 1);
    $sum2 += odbc_result($conn, 2);
    $sum3 += odbc_result($conn, 3);
}
```